# Java manual or reference in Eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to display javaSE manual or reference in eclipse IDE? For example to look up "List Object" documentation. In some IDE it is possible to select a word and press F1. I think it is called Javadoc.

Comment: You can attach the source for that library and use them as the reference by pressing `F3` over the class.

Comment: If you have the JDK installed (and not just the JRE), this is Eclipse's default behavior for the standard Java libraries - mouse over any class, method, etc and it'll pop up the Javadoc in a window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have attached the source code of the JDK, pressing F2 in the editor will open a tooltip with the javadoc of the method or class under the cursor, while pressing F3 will take you to the source code of that element.

Source code is automatically attached if you add a JDK to the build path (a JRE may not contain the source code). If I recall correctly, pressing F3 if you don't have the source code will prompt you for the location of source code (for a JDK, that's in src.zip).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but if you mouse over an identifier in eclipse it gives you the javadocs in window (looks like a tool-tip.)  You can go to your preferences/Java/Editor/Hovers and adjust what you want to bring up when you hover and even use a key modifier if you want.  Hope this helps.